# Свайп камеры как в игре Dead Trigger

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать свайп, где куда свайпнешь, туда и камера. Когда я свайпаю, камера работает верно только наполовину. Она крутится абсолютно по всем осям(Её заваливает). Может кто-нибудь помочь?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler {
    Vector2 delta;
    Quaternion rotationX;
    Quaternion rotationY;
    Quaternion originRotation;
    public GameObject Camera;

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        delta = eventData.delta;
        rotationX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(delta.x, Vector3.up);
        rotationY = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-delta.y, Vector3.right);
        originRotation = Camera.transform.rotation;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Camera.transform.rotation = originRotation *  rotationY * rotationX ;

    }

}
```

Comment: я не спец, но разве вы тут сами не крутите её по 2 осям?

Comment: Да, мне нужно крутить по X(Влево и вправо) и по Y(Вверх и вниз), но получается, когда я кручу по Х, то далее он крутит и по У уже от этого поворота. Мне как-то нужно сделать константное вращение, чтобы Х и У не зависели друг от друга