# Заморозка одной оси вращения

Tags: c#, unity3d

Интересует вопрос, как заморозить одну ось вращения, чтобы третья не менялась. Например, если использовать две оси вращения (X и Y ), то объест должен вращаться влево, вправо, вниз, вверх, но у меня еще меняется и ось Z. Как этого избежать?

```
public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler {
    Vector2 delta;
    Quaternion rotationX;
    Quaternion rotationY;
    Quaternion originRotation;
    public GameObject Camera;




    private void Start()
    {


    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        delta = eventData.delta;
        rotationX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(delta.x, Vector3.up);
        rotationY = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-delta.y, Vector3.right);
        originRotation = Camera.transform.rotation;

    }

    private void FixedUpdate() 
    {

        Camera.transform.rotation = originRotation *  rotationX * rotationY; 


    }


}
```

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от [вашего предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749201/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5-dead-trigger)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Свайп камеры как в игре Dead Trigger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749201/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bf-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5-dead-trigger)

Comment: Я знаю, просто, что на тот, что на этот никто не ответил. Решения я все-таки придумал